Where to find a PRINTED edition of משנה תורה with Yemenite punctuation?
I am familiar with the well-regarded מפעל edition according to כתבי יד תימנים, but it nevertheless uses standard נקוד,
for example:
שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר rather than שֶׁנֶּאֱמָר, and
לְפִיכָךְ rather than לְפִיכָּךְ, and
זְכֻיּוֹת rather than זָכִיּוֹת, and
אֶלָּא rather than אֵלָא, and
גֶּמִי rather than גֳּמִי,
etc., etc.
I am located in the United States but willing to order internationally if need be.

Welcome to MiYodeya Neev and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
